# Collection View displays duplicates on refresh and then deletes them

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, refresh

I'm working with a collectionView right now and when I activate the refresh control, it adds a duplicate picture to the data source set for every picture in the set, and then makes it disappear and things go back to normal by the time the refresh control is done. Here's a YouTube video I uploaded to clearly show you what is going on.

https://youtu.be/Q9ZFd-7tSRw

It would seem logical that the data source set would be getting the same data from the API I am using, then displaying it, the duplicate data then getting deleting from the array, and then the collection view being reloaded once more before the refresh control goes away. That's not how I want it to work obviously, but perhaps I have coded it wrong.

viewDidLoad:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier)

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.backgroundColor = goldenWordsYellow
    self.cellLoadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    revealViewControllerIndicator = 1
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 280

    collectionView!.delegate = self
    collectionView!.dataSource = self

    goldenWordsRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    goldenWordsRefreshControl.backgroundColor = goldenWordsYellow
    goldenWordsRefreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.collectionView!.addSubview(goldenWordsRefreshControl)

    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    navigationItem.title = "Pictures"

    setupView()

    populatePhotos()

    self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    self.cellLoadingIndicator.color = goldenWordsYellow
    self.cellLoadingIndicator.center = (self.collectionView?.center)!
    self.collectionView!.addSubview(cellLoadingIndicator)
    self.collectionView!.bringSubviewToFront(cellLoadingIndicator)


    /*
    self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    self.dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    let currentDateAndTime = NSDate()
    let updateString = "Last updated at " + self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDateAndTime)
    self.goldenWordsRefreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: updateString)
    */

}
```

populatePhotos:

```
func populatePhotos() {

    if populatingPhotos {
        return
    }
    populatingPhotos = true

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.temporaryPictureObjects.removeAllObjects()

    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Pictures(self.currentPage)).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)) {

            var nodeIDArray : [Int]

            if (JSON .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)) {

                for node in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let nodeIDValue = node.0
                    var lastItem : Int = 0

                    self.nodeIDArray.addObject(nodeIDValue)

                    if let pictureElement : PictureElement = PictureElement(title: "Picture", nodeID: 0, timeStamp: 0, imageURL: "http://goldenwords.ca/sites/all/themes/custom/gw/logo.png", author: "Staff", issueNumber: "Issue # error", volumeNumber: "Volume # error") {

                        pictureElement.title = node.1["title"] as! String
                        pictureElement.nodeID = Int(nodeIDValue)!

                        let timeStampString = node.1["revision_timestamp"] as! String
                        pictureElement.timeStamp = Int(timeStampString)!

                        if let imageURL = node.1["image_url"] as? String {
                            pictureElement.imageURL = imageURL
                        }

                        if let author = node.1["author"] as? String {
                            pictureElement.author = author
                        }

                        if let issueNumber = node.1["issue_int"] as? String {
                            pictureElement.issueNumber = issueNumber
                        }

                        if let volumeNumber = node.1["volume_int"] as? String {
                            pictureElement.volumeNumber = volumeNumber
                        }

                        lastItem = self.temporaryPictureObjects.count // Using a temporary set to not handle the dataSource set directly (safer).
                        self.temporaryPictureObjects.addObject(pictureElement)

                        let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.temporaryPictureObjects.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }
                    }

                }

                /* Sorting the elements in order of newest to oldest (as the array index increases] */
                let timeStampSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
                self.pictureObjects.sortUsingDescriptors([timeStampSortDescriptor])

            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.pictureObjects = self.temporaryPictureObjects
                self.collectionView!.reloadData()

                self.cellLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()

                self.currentPage++
                self.populatingPhotos = false
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

handleRefresh:

```
    func handleRefresh() {

    goldenWordsRefreshControl.beginRefreshing()

    self.pictureObjects.removeAllObjects()

    self.currentPage = 0

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.picturesCollectionView.bringSubviewToFront(cellLoadingIndicator)

    self.populatingPhotos = false
    populatePhotos()

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()

    goldenWordsRefreshControl.endRefreshing()

}
```

cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell

    if let pictureObject = pictureObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? PictureElement {

        let title = pictureObject.title ?? "" // if pictureObject.title == nil, then we return an empty string

        let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(pictureObject.timeStamp))
        let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

        let author = pictureObject.author ?? ""

        let issueNumber = pictureObject.issueNumber ?? ""
        let volumeNumber = pictureObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

        let nodeID = pictureObject.nodeID ?? 0

        let imageURL = pictureObject.imageURL ?? "http://goldenwords.ca/sites/all/themes/custom/gw/logo.png"

        cell.request?.cancel()

        if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL) as? UIImage {

            cell.imageView.image = image

        } else {

            cell.imageView.image = nil
            cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).responseImage() { response in
                if let image = response.result.value {
                    self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: imageURL)
                    if cell.imageView.image == nil {
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Due to the nature of how collection view cells are reused, you can only guarantee that a cell instance will match the right indexPath within the cellForItemAtIndexPath method. Since network requests are asynchronous, I would try to keep networking logic away from cell dequeuing/populating logic as much as possible. There is a library called SDWebImage that handles downloading/presenting/caching of images automatically, which may be a better solution.

Comment: I guess the main issue is that you don't `self.collectionView!.reloadData()` after `self.pictureObjects.removeAllObjects()`. Plus there is a cosmetic issue that you are calling `self.cellLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating();  goldenWordsRefreshControl.endRefreshing()` too early. You should call it in the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` block only.